# What is the most native way of adding a date picker to a Ruby on Rails 6 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, datepicker

I'm building a simple project where date input plays an important role. I don't want to add an another gem and heavy js library like jquery, bootstrap.

What is the **most lightweight solution** where I can let users to select/enter date? The **pure Ruby way**.

Thank you

---

EDIT:

I use **date_field** type, but it lets me enter any value. It does **not** format my input as date.
Code sample:

```
<%= form.date_field :date %>
```

[image]

---

**SOLUTION (temporary):**

Right! I needed to use **date_select**, not date_field : )

```
<%= form.date_select :date %>
```

[image]

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_date

Answer (score 3):

Your date field should also work but you can try this also , may be this work for you.

```
<%= form.date_field :date, min: 0.days.ago %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a whole heap of in built form helpers for selecting dates and other data types: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_date

I am not sure what you mean by 'pure ruby' as a date picker is html/css with some optional js, but the `select_date` form helper (and all other rails form helpers) are ruby objects under the hood, which, given arguments, will return HTML.

In addition to the above link, you should check out these docs for how to implement inside a form: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the browser support for date_field. It has improved quite a lot recently, see https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_input_type_date